# Gorm simple find with foreign key not working

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have a problem with foreign key selection with gorm on MySQL database.

I got a file dto.go:

```
package dto

import (
    "time"
)

type TaskResponse struct {
    ID          uint      `json:"id"`
    Title       string    `json:"title"`
    Description string    `json:"description"`
    Status      model.Status
    CreatedAt   time.Time `json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt   time.Time `json:"updated_at"`
}
```

A simple response object, but a task have a Status param.

I got a file task.go and status.go:

```
package model

// Status struct
type Status struct {
    ID   uint
    Name string
}

// Task struct
type Task struct {
    gorm.Model
    ID          uint
    Title       string
    Description string
    Status      Status `gorm:"ForeignKey:ID"`
    CreatedAt   time.Time
    UpdatedAt   time.Time
    DeletedAt   time.Time
}
```

The request:

```
 database.DB.Model(&model.Task{}).First(dest, conds...)
```

The problem is that I would like to add in TaskResponse the result of request, but all the task fields are retrieved but the Status object is always empty ... (I try many things like the actual `gorm:"ForeignKey:ID"`)

Someone know what is my problem?

Comment: You have already tried to use `gorm:"ForeignKey:StatusID"` instead of `gorm:"ForeignKey:ID"` ?

Comment: @J.Antonio Thanks for your reply, i already try and got this message : 

[error] invalid field found for struct example-todolist/dto.TaskResponse's field Status, need to define a foreign key for relations or it 
need to implement the Valuer/Scanner interface